# Guest Cart Selected Variations not working in Etsy API

Tags: etsy

When using the addToGuestCart method of the guestCart API endpoint the selected_variations parameter isn't working. I've tried sending the post data in JSON format with selected_variations being set to an array
containing two variations retrieved from the getInventory endpoint. The API request gives a 200 HTTP response but doesn't return any data, and the item doesn't appear in the Etsy cart. Making the same API call without the selected_variations set works fine. Can you please advise the correct format for including selected_variations in a call to the addToGuestCart endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const guestCart_data = {
  url: "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/guests/:guest_id/carts",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    guest_id: guestId,
    listing_id: listingId,                    
    quantity: 1,
    selected_variations: `{"47626759898" : "55055453743", "513": "86877352060"}`
    // selected_variations: `{"<property_id>" : "<value_ids>", "<property_id>": "<value_ids>"}`   
  },
};
```